# How do I remove the text "webform content" at the top of a block?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have several Drupal 8 webforms, some of which are embedded as blocks. At the top of each webform, I'm getting the "webform content" text.

[image: screenshot of webform content text]

How do I safely remove that text?

Comment: It looks like you are including the field label in the display.  If you created the block using a custom block type, look at the Display settings.  Mark the field label as hidden.  Not sure what to do if you are using the built in webform blocks.

Comment: That sounds promising! OK, newbie hat on: Where would I look for the Display settings? Would it be somewhere in the webform itself? Thanks!

Comment: If it was a custom block, it would be under admin->Structure->Block Layout->Types and then select your webform block.  Then it is a tab labeled Manage Display.

Comment: That was it - thank you!!!!

Comment: Thanks to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno for the editing recommendations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are including the field label in the display. If you created the block using a custom block type do the following:

- Go to Admin->Structure->Block Layout->Types
- Then select your WebForm block type
- There will be a tab labeled "Manage Display"
- On this page, mark the field label as hidden.

Not sure what to do if you are using the built in Webform blocks

Comment: Thanks again! Should I delete my "answer" below? I entered it before this appeared.

Comment: Technically yes on the delete, but I don't mind if you leave it.... will help you get your reputation points up a bit... and being new every little bit helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I went ahead and deleted it anyway :)